# Dojo Mobile form submit stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dojo, dijit.form, dojox.mobile

Listening for a `submit` event from a `dijit/Form/form` using DojoX Mobile has stopped working in Chrome on Android. This used to work, but doesn't anymore:

```
<form data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form">
    <input data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox"
        name="user" placeholder="Email"> <br />
    <input data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox" placeholder="Password"
        name="pass" type="password"> <br />
    <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

```
on(registry.byId('loginForm'), 'submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if (!this.isValid()) { return; }
    alert('valid submit fired');
});
```

After doing some digging, I've found that it started happening in Chrome 53. Testing [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rebolyte/dw5dd3ep/2/) with the dev tools and the device emulator in Chrome 52 works, but gives this warning in the console:

> A DOM Event generated from JavaScript has triggered a default action inside the browser. This behavior is non-standard and will be removed in M53, around September 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 for more details.

My guess is that it's coming from a synthesized, un-trusted event within DojoX (and that Chrome page points that direction as well), since a plain `<input type="submit" value="Log In">` successfully fires the event, but adding `dojox/mobile/button` causes it to fail.

Is this a bug that hasn't been addressed in Dojo (I've tested with 1.10.4 and 1.11.2)? Do I just need to use a workaround and have two separate listeners - one for the `submit` (i.e. the user hits enter) and one for the button `click`?

Comment: I had a very similar bug recently and it seemed to be because of Chrome 55 now supporting "pointer-events". So, during dojo intitilization, `has('pointer-events')` would return true, causing some extra code to run that made the Submit not work. The solution in my case was to upgrade to the latest Dojo. The [fix](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/commit/1d3a775302afdf33df9dea85457625aa9860de71) seems to have been made in 1.11.0 already

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip. I'll make sure that's not affecting my use case.

Comment: Honestly, I highly recommend you do not use the dojox/mobile widgets. They are catered highly to specific versions of iOS and mobile Chrome and have caused our development team so much grief. We ended up making our own library of input widgets that work on both mobile and desktop browsers. (we build responsive websites)